# parsing model to javascript object

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to parse my model into a `javascript` object in my `razor` view.
Everything worked fine until a `\n` char was added to some of the strings in my model. I've tried to solve this using several approaches but the only one that worked is giving me a syntax error in the view:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    //this one works but it's giving me a syntax error
    var model1 = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Articles));

    //this one just returns the json string
    var model2 = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Articles))';

    //this raises an "unexpected token error"
    var model3 = $.parseJSON('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Articles))');

    //also raises an "unexpected token error"
    var model4 = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Articles))');
});
</script>
```

Should I stay with option 1 and ignore the syntax error or is there another way to solve it?

Comment: The first one is fine - the 'syntax error' is just because of the `;` at the end and you can safely ignore it

Comment: @StephenMuecke please change your comment to an answer so I'll be able to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first syntax is correct

```
var model1 = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Articles));
```

The 'syntax' error is because of the `;` at the end, but it's valid, and the 'error' message can be safely ignored. The issue is with Visual Studio incorrectly reporting an error.

Answer (score 0):

I use `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Articles))` to parse my model to json. I would replace all my string with `'\n'` to `'\\n'` so i dont get the syntax error (prob do this in the controller)